# How to turn main method class to Junit test class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I wrote a small project named Sales Taxes on Intellij IDEA. To run the program, I included a main method. Now I need to write JUnit tests for the project. I do not have much experience about writing test classes. How can I turn my main method to Junit test class?

Here is the project that I constructed:

> Basic sales tax is applicable at a rate of 10% on all goods, except books, food, and medical products that are exempt.
>   Import duty is an additional sales tax applicable on all imported goods at a rate of 5%, with no exemptions.
>   When I purchase items I receive a receipt which lists the name of all the items and their price (including tax), finishing
>   with the total cost of the items, and the total amounts of sales taxes paid. The rounding rules for sales tax are that for
>   a tax rate of n%, a shelf price of p contains (np/100 rounded up to the nearest 0.05) amount of sales tax.
>   Write an application that prints out the receipt details for these shopping baskets...

#### Product.java

```
/*
Definition of Product.java class
Fundamental object for the project. 
It keeps all features of the product.
At description of the product, description of the input line for output line.
typeOfProduct: 0:other 1:food 2:book 3: medical products

*/

public class Product{

    private int typeOfProduct=0;
    private boolean imported=false;
    private double price=0;
    private double priceWithTaxes=0;
    private double taxes=0;
    private int quantity=0;
    private String description="";


    public Product(int quantity, int typeOfProduct, boolean imported, double price, String description)
    {
        this.quantity=quantity;
        this.typeOfProduct = typeOfProduct;
        this.imported = imported;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;

    }

    public void setTypeOfProduct(int typeOfProduct)
    {
        this.typeOfProduct = typeOfProduct;
    }

    public int getTypeOfProduct()
    {
        return typeOfProduct;
    }

    public void setImported(boolean imported)
    {
        this.imported = imported;
    }

    public boolean getImported()
    {
        return imported;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setTaxes(double taxes)
    {
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public double getTaxes()
    {
        return taxes;
    }

    public void setPriceWithTaxes(double priceWithTaxes)
    {
        this.priceWithTaxes = priceWithTaxes;
    }

    public double getPriceWithTaxes()
    {
        return priceWithTaxes;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

#### TaxCalculator.java

```
/*
Definition of TaxCalculator.java class
At constructor a Product object is taken.
taxCalculate method; adds necessary taxes to price of product.
Tax rules: 
    1. if the product is imported, tax %5 of price
    2. if the product is not food, book or medical goods, tax %10 of  price
typeOfProduct: 0:food 1:book 2: medical products 3:other
*/
public class TaxCalculator {

private Product product=null;

    public TaxCalculator(Product product)
    {
        this.product=product;
    }

    public void taxCalculate()
    {
        double price=product.getPrice();
        double tax=0;

        //check impoted or not
        if(product.getImported())
        {
            tax+= price*5/100;

        }

        //check type of product
        if(product.getTypeOfProduct()==3)
        {
            tax+= price/10;
        }

        product.setTaxes(Util.roundDouble(tax));
        product.setPriceWithTaxes(Util.roundDouble(tax)+price);
    }
}
```

#### Util.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
/*
Definition of Util.java class
It rounds and formats the price and taxes.
Round rules for sales taxes: rounded up to the nearest 0.05
Format: 0.00
*/

public class Util {

    public static String round(double value)
    {
        double rounded = (double) Math.round(value * 100)/ 100;

        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        rounded = Double.valueOf(df.format(rounded));

        return df.format(rounded).toString();
    }

    public static double roundDouble(double value)
    {
        double rounded = (double) Math.round(value * 20)/ 20;

        if(rounded<value)
        {
            rounded = (double) Math.round((value+0.05) * 20)/ 20;
        }

        return rounded;
    }

    public static String roundTax(double value)
    {
        double rounded = (double) Math.round(value * 20)/ 20;

        if(rounded<value)
        {
            rounded = (double) Math.round((value+0.05) * 20)/ 20;
        }

        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        rounded = Double.valueOf(df.format(rounded));

        return df.format(rounded).toString();
    }
}
```

#### SalesManager.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
/*
Definition of SalesManager.java class
This class asks to taxes to TaxCalculator Class and creates Product    objects.
 */
public class SalesManager {

    private String [][] arTypeOfProduct = new String [][]{
            {"CHOCOLATE", "CHOCOLATES", "BREAD", "BREADS", "WATER", "COLA", "EGG", "EGGS"},
            {"BOOK", "BOOKS"},
            {"PILL", "PILLS", "SYRUP", "SYRUPS"}
    };
    /*
     * It takes all inputs as ArrayList, and returns output as ArrayList
     * Difference between output and input arrayLists are Total price and Sales Takes.
     */
    public ArrayList<String> inputs(ArrayList<String> items)
    {
        Product product=null;
        double salesTaxes=0;
        double total=0;

        TaxCalculator tax=null;

        ArrayList<String> output=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++)
        {
            product= parse(items.get(i));
            tax=new TaxCalculator(product);
            tax.taxCalculate();

            salesTaxes+=product.getTaxes();
            total+=product.getPriceWithTaxes();

            output.add(""+product.getDescription()+" "+Util.round(product.getPriceWithTaxes()));

        }

        output.add("Sales Taxes: "+Util.round(salesTaxes));

        output.add("Total: "+Util.round(total));

        return output;
    }

    /*
     * The method takes all line and create product object.
     * To create the object, it analyses all line.
     * "1 chocolate bar at 0.85"
     * First word is quantity
     * Last word is price
     * between those words, to analyse it checks all words
     */
    public Product parse(String line)
    {
        Product product=null;

        String productName="";
        int typeOfProduct=0;
        boolean imported=false;
        double price=0;
        int quantity=0;
        String description="";

        ArrayList<String> wordsOfInput = new ArrayList<String>();

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

        String tmpWord="";
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            tmpWord=st.nextToken();
            wordsOfInput.add(tmpWord);
        }

        quantity=Integer.parseInt(wordsOfInput.get(0));

        imported = searchImported(wordsOfInput);

        typeOfProduct = searchTypeOfProduct(wordsOfInput);

        price=Double.parseDouble(wordsOfInput.get(wordsOfInput.size()-1));

        description=wordsOfInput.get(0);
        for(int i=1; i<wordsOfInput.size()-2; i++)
        {
            description=description.concat(" ");
            description=description.concat(wordsOfInput.get(i));
        }
        description=description.concat(":");

        product=new Product(quantity, typeOfProduct, imported, price, description);

        return product;
    }

    /*
     * It checks all line to find "imported" word, and returns boolean as imported or not.
     */
    public boolean searchImported(ArrayList<String> wordsOfInput)
    {
        boolean result =false;
        for(int i=0; i<wordsOfInput.size(); i++)
        {
            if(wordsOfInput.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("imported"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //typeOfProduct: 0:food 1:book 2: medical goods 3:other
    /*
     * It checks all 2D array to find the typeOf product
     * i=0 : Food
     * i=1 : Book 
     * i=2 : Medical goods
     */
    public int searchTypeOfProduct (ArrayList<String> line)
    {
        int result=3;
        for(int k=1; k<line.size()-2; k++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<arTypeOfProduct.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<arTypeOfProduct[i].length; j++)
                {
                    if(line.get(k).equalsIgnoreCase(arTypeOfProduct[i][j]))
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
 }
```

#### SalesTaxes.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SalesTaxes {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

        SalesManager sal = new SalesManager();

            /*
             * First input set
             */
        System.out.println("First input Set");
        System.out.println();

        input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("1 book at 12.49");
        input.add("1 music CD at 14.99");
        input.add("1 chocolate bar at 0.85");
        sal=new SalesManager();
        output= sal.inputs(input);

        for(int i=0; i<output.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(output.get(i));
        }

            /*
             * Second input set
             */
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Second input Set");
        System.out.println();

        input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00");
        input.add("1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50");
        sal=new SalesManager();
        output= sal.inputs(input);

        for(int i=0; i<output.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(output.get(i));
        }
            /*
             * Third input set
             */
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Third input Set");
        System.out.println();

        input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99");
        input.add("1 bottle of perfume at 18.99");
        input.add("1 packet of headache pills at 9.75");
        input.add("1 box of imported chocolates at 11.25");
        output= sal.inputs(input);

        for(int i=0; i<output.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(output.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not. Writing unit tests is pretty basic. Just put down a few scenario's for each method, with input and expected output, run them and assert the output. You will need to learn to work with JUnit, though: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can start with searching about *how to write unit tests*, maybe than you will not have this kind of question. The main point there is to test some piece of functionality. For example, in your case you should test *taxCalculate* method and check if in your product the tax was set correctly, probably you will need a getter for a product in this case.

Also, check this: [how to write a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751553/how-to-write-a-unit-test).

Answer (score 0):

A "unit test" is for one class.

So I wouldn't start with the main method: that wouldn't give you "unit tests". That would give you an "integration test" (testing a bunch of your classes all at once).

So, for unit tests, I would start by writing a `UtilTest` class to test just your `Util` class. That has public methods that can easily be given different inputs and the results asserted. e.g. what do you get back if you give `roundTax` zero, or 21.0, etc.?