# Should I test whether the returned type agrees with the desired one? (Polymorphism)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I do not know if my tests are appropriate and am I thinking in good way. I have a factory pattern. There is `ConverterContext` that returns desired object of given class.

```
public<K extends Converter> K getConverter(Class<K> converterClass){
    if(converterClass == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Optional<Converter> converter = converters.stream().filter(converterClass::isInstance).findFirst();
    return (K) converter.orElse(null);
}
```

Example of using:

```
Converter converter = converterContext.getConverter(ConverterRegisterUserDto.class);
```

I can test it on two ways:

1.

```
@Test
void getConverter_returnConverterRegisterUserDto() {
    //WHEN
    Converter converter = converterContext.getConverter(ConverterRegisterUserDto.class);
    //THEN
    assertTrue(ConverterRegisterUserDto.class.isInstance(converter));
}
```

2.

```
@Test
void getConverter_returnConverterRegisterUserDto() {
    //WHEN
    ConverterRegisterUserDto converter = converterContext.getConverter(ConverterRegisterUserDto.class);
    //THEN
    assertTrue(ConverterRegisterUserDto.class.isInstance(converter));
}
```

I think there is something wrong in this idea to test class like this. What is a correct way?

Comment: [It is impossible to answer your question because you do not provide a specification of what your code ought to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757321/545127).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever way you choose test the method, the result will be the same. I am quite certain that for almost all cases (except for things like change the signature of `getConverter`), the two ways of testing this will either both fail or both succeed.

The `Class` instance passed to the method will be used to determine what `K` is. In both ways of testing, you pass the same `Class` instance so `K` is the same. Since the return value type is `K`, instances of the same type will be returned in both ways of testing. This means that whether you declare `converter` as `Converter` or `ConverterRegisterUserDto` it will not matter at all. The type of the return value *will be* `ConverterRegisterUserDto`.

All of the above assumes that `getConverter`'s signature does not change. If you change `getConverter` so that it returns a `Converter` and keep everything else the same, then the second way of testing will fail by not compiling.

So decide which way to test it based on whether you want the test to fail when you accidentally change the signature.

Regarding the unchecked cast:

Don't worry about the unchecked cast. In your current version of `getConverter`, the unchecked cast will always succeed because you checked `converterClass::isInstance` before hand. The compiler is just too dumb to figure out. It might not always succeed if you change the body of the method of course. And that's one of the reasons why you write tests! To avoid accidentally changing something and breaking it.

Comment: So this test is useful? How could I test this method differently? I mean how would you test this method. I am trying to understand how to write useful and correct tests.

Comment: @mmprogr yes it is useful, for when you accidentally change the signature and/or body of the method.

Answer (score 0):

This function is actually safe at the type level due to its signature.

However, there is a problem in the unsafe cast in the return expression. Therefore, it would crash before failing, either test.

Comment: I dont know what a situation can crash this method. I can pass only objects that inherit after Converter. So why is the unsafe cast here?

Comment: The code is casting to K when there is no type guarantee that it is one.

Comment: Why is there no type guarantee? So how to make it type guarantee? And omitting the aspect of casting to K, How should looks test for this method?

Comment: It's not a problem since although converters.stream().filter(converterClass::isInstance).findFirst() returns a Optional<converter> since what actually is returned is correct the cast will be fine. However, if instead a different subclass of converter was returned the test would crash because of the incorrect cast rather than getting to the instance check.