# How to unit test method that contains try/catch blocks

Tags: java, junit, try-catch

I gotta to test method that is responsible for taking input.
It contains try/catch blocks. Should I unit test? If so, how to do it?

```
static String takeStringInput(Scanner input, String label) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println(label + ": ");
            return input.next();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Try again, bad input");
            input.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Mocking Scanner is impossible as no possible to mock final class.

Comment: [It is impossible to answer your question because you do not provide a specification of what your code ought to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757321/545127).

Answer (score 0):

Mock the Scanner (perhaps using Mockito) to return a valid value. This will test the "happy path." Then, modify the mock so that it returns an exception and then a valid value.

Comment: Something like this: `@Test
    void takeStringInput() {
        Scanner scanner = mock(Scanner.class);
        when(scanner.next()).thenReturn("test");
        InputTakers.takeStringInput(scanner,"brand");
    }` ? unfortunately error appear `Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Scanner
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class`