# Junit TestCases for Logger

Tags: java, logging, junit

I am having code for logging exception trace in case of any exception occurs in flow.

private void logExceptionStackTrace(Throwable throwable) {
        logger.error(throwable.getMessage() + " <==> " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(throwable));
    }

I want to write junit test cases covering above code.

I have passed parameters to my flow in such a way that NullPointer Exception will occur.

Regards
Aditya

Comment: what exactly is the question here? It's unclear, will you please rephrase the question and put some part of the code which is not working or issue you are facing?

Comment: [It is impossible to answer your question because you do not provide a specification of what your code ought to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757321/545127).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to register a special appender and collect the log events there. Then you can check for the existence of a certain event. How to do that depends on the logging framework you use.