# How to write test case for the given method

Tags: java, junit4

I want to write a test case for the given method

```
private String productCode;

public PaymentManager() {
    this.productCode = "SMART-TV;
}

@Override
public boolean isResponsibleFor(TransactionDetailResource resource) {
    return productCode.equals(resource.getProductCode());
}
```

How to write test case for this method

Comment: How would _you_ as a human test that method?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751553/how-to-write-a-unit-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a test class and a test function

```
@Test
public void testIsResponsibleFor() {
...
}
```

**(If you are using Eclipse, you can press Ctrl+J, It will automatically create the test class for you)**

Then in your test function you must create your two objects, one PaymentManager and one TransactionDetailResource.

```
PaymentManager p = PaymentManager();
TransactionDetailResource t = TransactionDetailResource();
t.setProductCode("SMART-TV")
```

I have assumed you got a Setter in your TransactionDetailResource class.

```
AssertThat(p.isResponsibleFor(t),is(Boolean.True))
```

This is a partial answer but It can gives you a starting point

Comment: Ctrl+J in what IDE? What if I wanted to use notepad ;)

Comment: I guess you have a point lol