# How to test that return value is correct

Tags: java, junit

I have to do jUnit test for class below. I want to test return value it's correct after method usage. I am sitting on in from 2 hours looking for help on google and here. Could someone help and give some tips? or example how it should looks?

```java
@Service
public class CurrencyToDBImpl implements CurrencyToDB
{

    @Override
    public ArrayList<CurrencyValue> createCurrencyListToDB(List<CurrencyRateList> list)
    {
        ArrayList<CurrencyValue> currencyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Rate> rateList = list.get(0).getRates();

        rateList.forEach(rate -> {
            if(rate.getCode().equals("USD") || rate.getCode().equals("GBP") ||
               rate.getCode().equals("EUR") || rate.getCode().equals("AUD"))
            {
                currencyArrayList.add(new CurrencyValue(rate.getMid(), rate.getCode(), rate.getCurrency()));
            }
        });

        return currencyArrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your test code look like?

Comment: that's the problem i don't have any idea how to start it ;/

Comment: There are some basics for getting started here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751553/how-to-write-a-unit-test

Comment: That may helps me interesting topic thank U